# Undefined property: stdClass::$contactno in C:\..\..\Joomla\administrator\components\com_helloworld\views\helloworlds\tmpl\default.php on line 92

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-component

> i add a contactno field in helloworld component backend. i add a no. of line code same as a Adding categories.
>
> the files loactions:
>
> 1. **admin/sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql**... i add a **contactno field**
> 2. **admin/models/forms/helloworld.xml**... i add a contactno field below greeting field

```
<field name="contactno" type="text" default="Some text" 
 description="COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_CONTACT_DESC"
label="COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_CONTACT_LABEL" 
size="10" />
```

> 3. **admin/models/fields/helloworld.php** i add a query in **protected function getOptions()**

```
$query->select('#__helloworld.id as id,greeting,#__helloworld.contactno as contactno,#__categories.title as category,catid');
```

> 4. **admin/views/helloworlds/tmpl/default.php**...i add a contactno field  **th** in **table** below author field

```
<th width="30%">
                <?php echo JHtml::_('searchtools.sort', 'COM_HELLOWORLD_CONTACTNO', 'contactno', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
            </th>
```

> and **td** below author

`<td align="center"> <?php echo $row->contactno; ?> </td>`

> when i run a helloworld component i got **error**
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$contactno in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla\administrator\components\com_helloworld\views\helloworlds\tmpl\default.php on line 92
>
> what is my mistake...where define a new field...?

Answer (score 0):

> i solve by adding in associative array of configuration settings.
>   file location is: **admin/models/helloworlds.php**
>    i add a new fields **contactno** in array and updating in query
>     of **getListQuery()**

```
 $query->select('a.id as id, a.greeting as greeting, a.contactno as contactno, a.published as published, a.created as created')
```